# Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have prepared a Silverlight application and my database is in the server. Its running smoothly for small set of data but for large data set giving an error : Remote Serve returned an error:notFound. How can i resolve it,please any one solve this problem.
I have build it in ASP.NET with C#. So kindly provide the solution in C# if possible.

Comment: We need alot more information than that to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: It would be useful if we could see the method that's generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe anyone will be able to just give you an answer. But we might be able to help you find the answer.

I would first find out if the problem is in the web service, or Silverlight. To do so, call the same method on your web service with the same parameters. (You may need to use debug to find out just what that is.) Just before the async call you should be able to find the url that will be called. Copy that and paste it into the browser and see what the result is.

If the web method is throwing an exception, you will need to debug the web method for your service. Otherwise you need to figure out why Silverllight isn't able to handle the returned message.